# Join all prefixed tables into one

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have multiple tables i.e. `jibs3_posts`, `jibs4_posts`, `jibs5_posts`.. and so on. Is there any way I could make a join between all these tables with some sort of wildcard for the `jibs`-prefix?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM 'jibs*_posts';
```

P.S. Sorry if this is a duplicate, but couldn't find any solution.

P.P.S This is a WordPress Multisite

Comment: No.  You can fix your data model by having one table, `jibs_posts`, that combines the data from these subtables.

Comment: Why do you have all those tables? Wouldn't one, common jibs_post table be better?

Comment: @jarlh Wordpress multisite network seems to create this mess

Comment: @RiggsFolly Probably, took over a WP-project last updated 2008...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Get your table names:

```
declare @row_number int = 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE JibsTables (table_name varchar(50), num int)

INSERT INTO JibsTables (table_name, num)
SELECT table_name, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema='your_database_name'
  AND table_name like 'jibs%'
```

2- Create dynamic query in a loop.

```
declare @counter = 1
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @temptable nvarchar(100);
declare @limit int = (select count(*) from JibsTables)

while @counter <= @limit
begin
   set @temptable = select table_name from JibsTables where num = @counter

   if @counter <> @limit
   begin
      set @sql = @sql + ' select * from ' + @temptable + ' union'
   end
   else
   begin
      set @sql = @sql + ' select * from ' + @temptable + ';'
   end

   set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

3- Execute your dynamic query

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql
EXECUTE stmt1
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

I am familiar with the MSSQL syntax, tried my best to find the correct syntax for mysql, but logic is clear I believe. Hope all is good, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not able to receive the table names from my database using the first query. The temp table JibsTables returns empty

Comment: Should be a percent `%` instead of an asterisk `*`

Comment: @Jesper can u try again now? make sure the select query returns resultset

Comment: And better use 'jibs%posts' as template.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative. If new `jibs` tables aren't being added too frequently, you could create a view that `UNION`s all of them together, then write your queries against the view. That way, you only need to do the tedious typing once.

If memory serves (it's been a while since I played around in a Wordpress site) you should be able to add the necessary object to the database.

Something to the effect of:

```
CREATE VIEW v_jibs_posts AS
  SELECT <column_list> FROM jibs1_posts
  UNION
  ...<SELECTS from all the tables>
  UNION
  SELECT <column_list> FROM jibs<n>_posts
```

Then just add an additional `UNION` to the view as new tables are created by the app.

Of course, if they're popping up frequently, this would be too cumbersome to maintain.

**Edit**: If you wanted to get fancy, you could use Eray Balkanli's dynamic SQL to generate an `ALTER VIEW` statement to pick up new tables, and then schedule that to run periodically.

Comment: Unfortunately, they will be added quite frequently, so that will be too hard to maintain

Comment: I was typing an edit when you commented that could ease some of the maintenance pain, depending on your tolerance for perhaps missing data by querying the view between updates.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with SQL, but there are alternative approaches.

If there is a good reason to abandon the multiple tables (i.e., if the data model would be satisfied by one, common table), you can pursue a one-time conversion from the multiple tables into a single table.

If there is a good reason to retain the multiple tables (i.e., if there is something about your data model, or some logistical constraint, that dictates such an arrangement), then this is a good situation for combining tools.  Specifically, you can use your favorite programming or scripting language to generate the SQL that references all of the tables, then employ that generated SQL.

Many programming languages would allow you to both generate the SQL and utilize it in the same program, through database bindings.

**EDIT** : I see that you've added the `wordpress` tag (I began composing my answer before it was there), so I'm not sure how much my answer applies.  That is to say, I'm not sure how much access you have to interact directly with the database.  If you are constrained by what Wordpress requires and/or the manner in which Wordpress allows you to run the SQL you are wanting to run, then my generic MySQL / SQL answer might not be much help.

Still, my general advice would be to approach the problem with all the tools you have in your toolbox, and consider a combination-of-strengths approach, since SQL does not support wildcards for table names.

Comment: I do have access to the database, but such a refactor would be too large at the moment

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'jibs%_posts';
```

this will list all the tables with that naming scheme.

Then you can concatenate all the tables (if they have the same number of columns) with a [`UNION`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM jibs_posts
UNION
// ... more SELECTS
UNION
SELECT * FROM jibsX_posts;
```

Comment: This would probably be too hard to maintain since more tables will be added quite frequently